# Exponential transform of an integer sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, integer, polynomials

The [exponential generating function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialGeneratingFunction.html) (e.g.f.) of a sequence \$a_n\$ is defined as the [formal power series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FormalPowerSeries.html) \$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n\$.

When \$a_0 = 0\$, we can apply the exponential function \$\exp\$ on this formal power series:

\$\begin{align}
\exp(f(x)) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} f(x)^n \\
 &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \left(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_m}{m!} x^m\right)^n \\
 &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{b_n}{n!} x^n \\
\text{where} \\
b_0 &= 1 \\
b_n &= \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1} a_k b_{n-k} \text{ when } n>0
\end{align}\$

This is the exponential generating function of the sequence \$b_n\$. If all \$a_n\$ are integers, then all \$b_n\$ are also integers. So this is a tranformation of integer sequences.

It seems that OEIS call this the Exponential transform. But I can't find a reference to its definition.

Here are some examples on OEIS:

- [A001477](https://oeis.org/A001477) (the nonnegative integers, \$0,1,2,3,4,\dots\$) -> [A000248](https://oeis.org/A000248) (\$1,1,3,10,41,\dots\$)
- [A001489](https://oeis.org/A001489) (the nonpositive integers, \$0,-1,-2,-3,-4,\dots\$) -> [A292952](https://oeis.org/A292952) (\$1, -1,-1,2,9,\dots\$)
- [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045) (Fibonacci numbers, \$0,1,1,2,3,\dots\$) -> [A256180](https://oeis.org/A256180) (\$1,1,2,6,21,\dots\$)
- [A160656](https://oeis.org/A160656) (\$0\$ and the odd primes, \$0,3,5,7,11,\dots\$) -> [A353079](https://oeis.org/A353079) (\$1,3,14,79,521,\dots\$)
- [A057427](https://oeis.org/A057427) (\$0,1,1,1,1,\dots\$) -> [A000110](https://oeis.org/A000110) (Bell numbers, \$1,1,2,5,15,\dots\$)

### Task

Given a finite integer sequence, compute its Exponential transform.

The length of the input sequence is always greater than \$0\$. Its \$0\$th term is always \$0\$. You can omit the leading \$0\$ in the input.

If the input sequence has length \$n\$, you only need to output the first \$n\$ terms of the output sequence.

Input and output can be in any reasonable format, e.g., a list, an array, a polynomial, a function that takes \$i\$ and returns the \$i\$th term (0-indexed or 1-indexed), etc.

You may also take the input sequence and an integer \$i\$, and output the \$i\$th term (0-indexed or 1-indexed) of the output sequence.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Example Python code

This example code uses the above recurrence formula. There are other formulas that might give shorter answers.

```python
import math

def exponential_transform(a):
    b = [0] * len(a)
    b[0] = 1
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        b[i] = sum(math.comb(i-1, j-1) * a[j] * b[i - j] for j in range(1, i + 1))
    return b
```

### Testcases

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] -> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1] -> [1, 1, 1, 0, -3, -8, -3, 56]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] -> [1, 1, 3, 10, 41, 196, 1057, 6322]
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7] -> [1, -1, -1, 2, 9, 4, -95, -414]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55] -> [1, 1, 2, 6, 21, 86, 404, 2121, 12264, 77272, 525941]
[0, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19] -> [1, 3, 14, 79, 521, 3876, 31935, 287225]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] -> [1, 1, 2, 5, 15, 52]
[0, 1, 2, 5, 15, 52] -> [1, 1, 3, 12, 60, 358]
[0, 1, 3, 12, 60, 358] -> [1, 1, 4, 22, 154, 1304]
[0, 1, 4, 22, 154, 1304] -> [1, 1, 5, 35, 315, 3455]
[0, 1, 5, 35, 315, 3455] -> [1, 1, 6, 51, 561, 7556]
```

Comment: A worked example would be nice.

Comment: Is the solution allowed to fail due to floating-point errors?

Comment: @CommandMaster Yes, allowed.

Comment: @emanresuA Added a Python example.

Comment: Can we omit the leading 0 in the input?

Comment: @Steffan Yes, you can.

Comment: Seems to be EXP on [OEIS transforms (Maple)](https://oeis.org/transforms.txt) (search for "EXP:="), which can be accessed from [this page](https://oeis.org/transforms.html). Not sure what the leading `1+` in the comment means though. There's also [a wiki page for sequence transforms](https://oeis.org/wiki/Sequence_transforms) but many aren't documented yet.

Comment: Can we omit the leading 1 in the output?

Answer (score 11):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>21</s> <s>20</s> <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
L©ææʒ˜{®Q}€€gèPO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f59DKw8sOLzs16fSc6kPrAmsfNa0BovTDKwL8//835oo20FEw1lEw1VEw11EwNARiIM8QxLaMBQA)

Returns the \$ i \$-th term, zero indexed. It runs in complexity \$ \Omega(2^{2^i}) \$, so it can only work in a reasonable time for \$ i \leq 4 \$.

## Explanation

We will define \$ c_n = \frac{a_n x^n}{n!} \$.

In the expression
$$ \left(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_m}{m!} x^m\right)^n = \left(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} c_m\right)^n $$

we know from the multinomial theorem that the coefficient of
\$ \prod {c_m ^ {k_m}} \$
is
$$ \frac{n!}{\prod{k_m !}} $$
The \$ n! \$ cancels with the \$ \frac{1}{n!} \$ in \$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \left(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_m}{m!} x^m\right)^n \$, so we get
$$ \exp(f(x)) = \sum \frac{\prod{c_m ^ {k_m}}}{\prod{k_m!}} $$
If the exponent of \$ x \$ in the equation is \$ j \$, we get that \$ \sum k_m m = j \$. If we create a sequence \$ d_m \$ by repeating \$ m \$ \$ k_m \$ times, we get that \$ d_m \$ is a partition of \$ j \$.

Now that we have a mathematical expression for how much time each partition of \$ i \$ occurs, we can think of a combinatorical one.

By playing with equations, we can find out that the coefficient of \$ \prod {a_{d_i}} \$ is the number of unique ways to divide a set with \$ j \$ elements to sets of sizes \$ d_i \$. Therefore, we can generate a set of size \$ j \$, list all of its separations to other sets, take the size of each set in those separations, index that size to \$ a \$, take the product of each, and take the total sum.

```
L       push the list 1...input index
©       save it in register ® (without popping)
æ       take its powerset
æ       take the powerset's powerset
ʒ       and only keep sets such that
 ˜       if you flatten them
 {       and sort the result
 ®       and then push the original list
 Q       they compare equal
}
€        for each of those sets
 €       map each of its sets
  g      to its size
è        index that size into the input list
P        take the product of each list
O        and take the sum
```

If the index is 0, `L` returns `[1, 0]`, and no array sorted can be equal to it, so the filter returns an empty list. The map and index then do nothing, then `P` multiplies it to get `1`, which `O` preserves.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>37</s> 24 bytes

```
BellY[#,,#2]~Sum~{,0,#}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU9dasJAEH7PKRYDkugnZnezKoIllD4WWupTCXmYyiYGki2YLW0J8RC9QU/YI6TrKgPDfD/zMdOSPeqWbH2g8aks8/23sfS13U4O7@2kYNGMPdQdvTWaOR/7pJOpTcVmcRCUu/FeN81rHgKhKM77j/bcI0E4TEerO9uxHev7BL4G9BwCEikUVlh7nGBxadfBM1ePwgZcQnBIZ1c3xdctR4ErKOGRBBdYJZBq43EKIZycuogk9YxyGqTbkKlLG4KI/n5@n0@1sTkt7qIyD90dVEyX2QuZSmcRnz9qU9ljRnFcxGyZMf/Q@A8)

Based on the Mathematica code given by [Vladimir Reshetnikov](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Vladimir_Reshetnikov) on OEIS [A256180](https://oeis.org/A256180). Takes the 0-indexed item to output and the list.

*-13 bytes thanks to alephalpha*

Comment: Shorter: `BellY[#,k,Rest@#2]~Sum~{k,0,#}&`. Or even shorter if you don't take the leading zero: `BellY[#,k,#2]~Sum~{k,0,#}&`

Comment: @alephalpha Thanks, you can save even two more bytes with `BellY[#,,#2]~Sum~{,0,#}&`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 59 bytes

```hs
f@(a:b)&g@(c:d)=a*c:zipWith(+)(b&g)(f&d)
_&_=[]
e b=1:e b&b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7NCsJADITvfYo9Lbs6C92ftFoo@BYeRKS1rRZ/UU@@fE31pCuBIeTLTLKv7of2eByGbqGqotZyt1DbotFlNdkWz/667B97NdWqljutOtnoZCM35WqdtKIubcEq6@FU9WdRiuaSCHG99eeHUK1YpXjXWn9NLc/MKJ8mog4eAYQM@Q9jl3EwHibAEEwGk0f2TwBhBuvhLDxn0c/WyHNYO65YbuZ/Ut715zmCJZCLCCc5ZCk8zSIW4BzbAt9LQ0SJPfCc6sP46fAC)

`e` accepts the sequence as a list of integers without the leading 0.

If \$f(x)\$ is the e.g.f. of \$a_n\$, then \$f(0) = a_0\$ and \$f'(x)\$ is the e.g.f. of \$a_{n + 1}\$.  So this program is a direct encoding of the product rule \$[f(x)g(x)]' = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)\$ and the chain rule \$[e^{f(x)}]' = e^{f(x)}f'(x)\$.

Comment: I think you can write the base case as `_&l=l` to save a byte

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `R`, 16 bytes

```
ṗṗ'fs¹ɾ⁼;vvLİvΠ∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJSIiwiIiwi4bmX4bmXJ2ZzwrnJvuKBvDt2dkzEsHbOoOKIkSIsIiIsIjNcblswLCAxLCA1LCAzNSwgMzE1LCAzNDU1XSJd)

Port of Command Master's 05AB1E answer, upvote that!

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), <del>103</del> 92 bytes

saved 11 bytes thanks to the comment of @alephalpha

Golfed vesrion, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDdboMwDIXv9xRWdxM6R8KBAF2Vt9gd4iJUtApaWwRsr8@csR8QqRQriXU@H9ud7Z28dNN0FjYytflsTuO9F88WHcbRsS6pMnQ8c8oZhZyuS1eZ4eMqWkPoJGHtbvers@/CSYWtpGhvy/aFqj0rZVtFXGTqencbxe6tGUY42aEBeoUdwlmUMcL/8eKnjVYttPQtlPP1@wljyRpTCAlCiqARMoQ8DKULyLvwSCCZkwxKJiWj8gGr14Z/nowV/OWX4lziW9DhCtmiwgzmDNIMk38fwmC@sf45YXmxWQ1bEYdWYeCwBnw3DGW@TV2EEYrXDI@tlHdJ/Thx@oCiNaW9A4dvLknnvU1f)

```
f(a)=b=vector(#a,i,0);b[1]=1;for(i=2,#a,b[i]=sum(j=1,i-1,binomial(i-2,j-1)*a[j+1]*b[i-j]));b
```

Ungolfde version, modified from the provided Python example code

```
exponential_transform(a) = {
    b = vector(#a, i, 0); \\ Initialize b as a zero vector of the same length as a
    b[1] = 1; \\ Set the first element of b to 1

    for(i=2, #a,
        b[i] = sum(j=1, i-1, binomial(i-2, j-1) * a[j+1] * b[i-j])
    );
    return(b);
}
print("Test case 1: ", exponential_transform([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]));
print("Test case 2: ", exponential_transform([0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1]));
print("Test case 3: ", exponential_transform([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));
print("Test case 4: ", exponential_transform([0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7]));
print("Test case 5: ", exponential_transform([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]));
print("Test case 6: ", exponential_transform([0, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]));
print("Test case 7: ", exponential_transform([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]));
print("Test case 8: ", exponential_transform([0, 1, 2, 5, 15, 52]));
print("Test case 9: ", exponential_transform([0, 1, 3, 12, 60, 358]));
print("Test case 10: ", exponential_transform([0, 1, 4, 22, 154, 1304]));
print("Test case 11: ", exponential_transform([0, 1, 5, 35, 315, 3455]));
```

Comment: In PARI/GP, curly braces are only requires for multiline functions, and the last expression in automatically returned. So this can be `f(a)=b=vector(#a,i,0);b[1]=1;for(i=2,#a,b[i]=sum(j=1,i-1,binomial(i-2,j-1)*a[j+1]*b[i-j]));b`.

Comment: @alephalpha thanks for your comment!   :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 85 bytes

```
import math
f=lambda n,l:sum(math.comb(n-1,i)*l[i]*f(n-i-1,l)for i in range(n))+(n<1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZBBboMwEEX3nGKUlZ18KmzjBEWlt-gKsSAtbiyBQeAsepZusmnv1Jt0WWPophrJ8vsz_vb3x9f47q-Du98_b96kxfez7cdh8tQ3_pqYsmv6y2tDDt15vvVsUR9ehv7CXCpg-b6rbL03gWzgjpthIkvW0dS4t5Y5zg_MPQq-mf_4dvYzlVRVGWLVqAQkFHJoHHGKnCFdlnUTlXVGo4BQkAIqjOutE2vz0RAaWkZSEBLHDEoXkXNIGdp5sMjyqOjQgwonVB7d1jtOEMFQ1XWSLHH8Eie--5wQjZN1nnnQrnzagaqFDLMgzzn9S9-1jnl-ELze8v998i8)

Doesn't take the leading zero in the input. If that's not allowed, I will change.
Based on the Maple code given by [Alois P. Heinz](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Alois_P._Heinz) in [A007446](https://oeis.org/A007446) and [A353079](https://oeis.org/A353079).

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 36 bytes

```
ＦＬθ⊞υ∨¬ιΣＥυ××κ§θ⁻ιλ∨¬λ÷Π…⁻ιλιΠ…·¹λＩυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLCsIwEEX3fsUsJxDBrl2Jbgo@irorXYQ0toNpYvMo/n1sLUovw3Dnca5shZNW6JQe1gEelWlCiz1jUETfYuRwcXi2AYlxuMUOT@I1be/UKY9zf3LYhdzU6o09hxOZ6JE4aMbYH9ejzU040EC1wsLZOsqAV2EahQuCA03Q754bqaOnQc2P2Rz61XZVODIB98IHjOOcUlluOGTLqqq0HvQH) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: A translation of the recurrence formula given in the question, except the subscript of `b` is used as the loop index, and the combination has to be written out as a ratio of products of ranges.

33 bytes using the newer version of Charcoal on ATO:

```
ＦＬθ⊞υ∨¬ιΣＥυ××κ§θ⁻ιλ÷Π…⁻ιλιΠ…·¹λＩυ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY89CsJAEIV7TzGkmoUNaCdYiTYBf4LahRTrZmMG40b3J3gXGwtFD-BlvI2GKGR4DLw33wzM5SkLYWQlyuv17l0eDt-vvDKAM6V3rsATYxB7W6DnsDS4qBwS47D2B5yLY5Nu6KAstn3PYewinakznjjMSXuLxKFk7LsTaTelmjKFsakyLx2uhN4p7GAcqCH_80jL0luqVQsO2ktNjXqxIe1wIqxD__U3u5X298EjCcK6DNJXkvQ5DLpK0xb5AA) Link is to verbose version of code.